# How to reverse a stack without returning anything

Tags: python

```
a={}#dictionary
b=0
while(stack.is_empty()==False):
    b=b+1
    a={b:stack.pop()} 
else:
    for i in range(b, 0, -1):
       stack.push(a[i])
```

I think this should work but it doesn't,
Key error and empty stack errors are raised

Comment: Both errors for the same input?  Impressive!

Comment: A dictioanry is hashed not rodered. You cannot use a dictionary. You are better off directly iterating over the stack ... `while not stack.is_empty(): newstack.push( stack.pop() )`

Comment: Or just use SonicArg's method of reverse ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reversing a stack, you can consider the stack as a list and do:

```
stack.reverse()
```

instead of popping and pushing in a spare stack. From [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> Reverse the elements of the list, in place

```
>>> a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[333, 1234.5, 1, 333, -1, 66.25]
```

**EDIT:** As rephrased by the questioner, if you want to reverse a stack into a new one, you can do:

```
def reverse_and_return(stack):
  newstack = []  # New list/stack
  for element in stack:
    newstack.insert(0, element)  # Push new element first
  return newstack
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a={b:stack.pop()}
```

That will replace `a` with a new dictionary each iteration. To add keys to the existing dictionary, do

```
a[b] = stack.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood, try

```
>>> {'b':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5][::-1]}
{'b': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]} #list inside a dictionary are reversed
```